# Chrome Transitions doesnt work. all other browsers do

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've created a menu that adjusts itself as it gets past a certain point of the screen. Everything works great, except for transitions and only on Chrome.
I tried adding a -webkit- version of the transition, but it doesn't work either.

This is my CSS

```
.past-main {
    height: 97px !important;
    margin-left: -40px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px !important;
    position: absolute;
   -webkit-transition: height 300ms opacity 300ms top 300ms ease 0s;
   transition: height 300ms, opacity 300ms,top 300ms ease 0s;
   opacity: 1!important;
   height: 90px !important;
   margin-top:0px !important;


}
.past-maina {
    -webkit-transition: top 800ms ease 0s;
    transition: top 800ms ease 0s!important;
    top:0px!important;

}
.past-mainb {
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease 0s;
    transition: all 800ms ease 0s;
    margin-top:0px!important;

}
```

Comment: how about creating a code snippet so people can debug the behavior?

Comment: What are you transitioning into? Also transitioning the height when it is set to !important probably don't work as it overrides any other height property. Might want to remove that and try.

Comment: It'll definitely be all the `important` statements...you really don't need those.

Comment: removed all of them. still not working

Answer (score 0):

To add more context, the various levels of your header menu gets those classes applied when the user scrolls past a certain point:

- some wrapper elements get `past-maina` and `past-main`
- each menu item (they are `li` elements) gets `past-mainb`

Before scrolling down, each menu item has varying `margin-top` values; afterwards they all get `0`. These are set with style rules like

```
.desktop-nav ul li:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Now, this selector has a [higher specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) (22) than your `.past-mainb` selector (10), which, I'm guessing, is why you added the `!important` annotation to the latter's rule: otherwise, it wouldn't take effect.

But this had an undesired side effect: [important declarations *always* win over transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascade-origin)! Thus, if you want your transitions to take effect you can't use `!important`.

The simple cheat is to up the specificity of the "past main" style rules. For example, add an ID selector. Or perhaps better: instead of adding a class when the user scrolls, remove a "before main" class instead, and rewrite all the rules giving specific menu-item margins to use it:

```
.desktop-nav.before-main ul li:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```